# How to plot beautifully the segmentation of time series (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas time indexed pandas dataframe called small_roll_changepoint looks like following

```
        roll   changepoint
index      
t1      1.1    0
t2      1.2    0
t3      0.1    0
t4      12     1
t5      11     0
```

changepoint columns is either 0 and 1, which marks the changepoint on time series roll. The exact visualization I want to achieve is to segment the roll series where changepoint is 1

codes I can come up to

```
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
small_roll_changepoint.plot(style=['-',':'],ax=ax)
pl.show()
```

it's ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to achieve your desired visualization, but one way to "pretty up" the graph a little bit is to add the following line.

```
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
```

and replace

```
fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
```

with

```
pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18.5,10.5)
```

This will definitely make the `matplotlib` graph look much more presentable.